# Rails Nested Attribute Forms and HTTP Request Limits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, form-submit

I've read many posts about doing Rails nested forms, which I think I understand. And I've read several posts about limits on HTTP GET requests, which I also think I understand. But I have not seen any question/answer regarding their combination, so here goes...

If the limit on an HTTP request is somewhere between 256 and 2048 (approximately, and depending upon browser, server configuration, etc, etc), does this then put a caution on how elaborate one gets with a nested attribute form in Rails? So I have, for example, an Service Invoice form which has work items (that include descriptions for each) as a nested attribute (separate SQL table) and a list of payments (another nested attributes). If make all this editable on one form and want to do a Submit button to update all the data, does Rails attempt to pass all this stuff in one HTTP request string back to the server? So then, if it's possible that all my invoice header info, work item descriptions, and payment descriptions all total more than, say, about 2K bytes of info, I will not be able to use a single nested form for data entry?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP request limits you mention are only for GET requests; that is, those are limits on the length of a URL, and in a GET request, all data is included in the URL.

However, a form submission that is meant to create or update a resource should always be a POST or PUT request, not a GET.  The only time this would be an issue would be if you were, for example, doing a very elaborate search form, so that you were filling out a complex form but doing a GET request (i.e. not doing any update).  That seems unlikely, and in that case it would probably be appropriate to turn that into a POST (e.g. identify a new resource that you're creating).

Comment: Thanks JacobM. I'm still navigating my way through the different request types. This was quite helpful.